# DispatcherServlet not calling spring controller in rest service project

Tags: eclipse, rest, spring-mvc, spring-4

I created a sample REST webservices project and provided controller to handle urls but when I run it on tomcat it always picks index.jsp file rather than moving to controller and executing server side logic from controller, how can we achieve it.
I have created a maven dynamic web project and in the web.xml has below content:-

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My Project structure is as shown :-

[image]

springrest-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.restwebservice" />

</beans>
```

EDIT:-
I see the target folder has .java files inside classes which I suspect should be .class =>

[image]

Comment: can you share springrest servlet also?

Comment: added springrest-servlet.xml

Comment: Lose the index.jsp file, it would seem to check for that first.

Answer (score 1):

Move your java class to src/main/java folder from src/main/resource keeping package structure as it is.Read [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) to understand the directory structure.

from the link.

> one for resources (the structure which is copied to the target classpath given the default resource definition).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add mapping to your controller?

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

   @RequestMapping("/") 
   public Long testApi(){}
```

Comment: Yes using @GetMapping("/customers")

Comment: what happens when you access /customers?

Comment: it gives 404 page not found
in console-
Jul 11, 2017 5:48:57 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringWebServiceDemo/customers] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'